# Featured Image not shown and getting error "Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int"

Tags: post-thumbnails, wp-error

First of all I'm using twentyeleven theme, I created a custom template page to insert posts. **It has 4 submit forms. it is working well, also setting feature image is ok for 3 forms except the first one it is not setting feature image for the post even it upload the image (using upload form and also using image from link) and attach it to the post**, what makes me crazy is that I'm using the same function to set feature image, but I don't know why it is not working with the first submit form

This is my code for setting feature image:

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$filename = basename($image_url);
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path'])){
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
}else{
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $pid );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $pid, $attach_id );
```

I'm getting these errors

1- In the the **home** page and **edit post** in admin area:

`Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in SITE_ROOT/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4294`
which leads me to `wp_attachment_is_image` function in the main post.php page

```
function wp_attachment_is_image( $post_id = 0 ) {
    $post_id = (int) $post_id;
    if ( !$post = get_post( $post_id ) )
        return false;

    if ( !$file = get_attached_file( $post->ID ) )
        return false;

    $ext = preg_match('/\.([^.]+)$/', $file, $matches) ? strtolower($matches[1]) : false;

    $image_exts = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'jpe', 'gif', 'png' );

    if ( 'image/' == substr($post->post_mime_type, 0, 6) || $ext && 'import' == $post->post_mime_type && in_array($ext, $image_exts) )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I tested `$post_id` by is_int and fount that is is integer

2- In the home page :
`Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to int in SITE_ROOT/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3814`

which leads me to `_get_non_cached_ids` in `functions.php` page

```
function _get_non_cached_ids( $object_ids, $cache_key ) {
    $clean = array();
    foreach ( $object_ids as $id ) { 
        $id = (int) $id;
        if ( !wp_cache_get( $id, $cache_key ) ) {
            $clean[] = $id;
        }
    }

    return $clean;
}
```

I tested `$id` by is_int() and I got that **it is not integer**

How can I fix that problem, and why only this first form is not setting feature image even it is attach the image to the post

Comment: I double check it using is_int and echo the message saying `id 7548 is not int`, How could `7548` be not int?

Comment: I used `get_defined_vars()` but I don't know where I have to look because I got hundreds of variables

Comment: I tried to echo `$id` which in foreach for `_get_non_cached_ids` function but I got that error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in SITE_ROOT/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3814

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fix the problem

I keep tracking every where in my code and start to comment my code parts step by step.

as I said in my question I have a form that do `upload the image (using upload form and also using image from link)`, and that was the main problem **a conflict between uploading using upload form and using image link**

So when I comment the function which I'm using to upload image from PC the code work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

One of your function calls is returning a [`WP_Error`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Error) object and you are trying to use that object as if it were an integer. This is the likely culprit:

```
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

I can't say why as the code is out of context and you didn't include `$new_post`.

It is also possible that you are causing trouble for yourself by including a Core file directly:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

That file may require other files that are not being loaded properly.

Comment: @ s_ha_dum  I use `is_wp_error` function to check if `$pid` has errors or not and I didn't get any error.   
also `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');` is recommended by all users, What I can't know is that why only first form not working even I'm using same function to set featured image and the page contains 3 other working, also as I mentioned the not working one is adding contents and attaching image to post normally, and `only has problem in setting featured image to that post`

Comment: How did you use `is_wp_error`?

Comment: @ s_ha_dum
I use it like so:
`$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
if ( is_wp_error( $pid ) ) {
   $error_string = $pid->get_error_message();
   echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';exit;
 }else{
 echo 'pid is ok';exit;
 }`
I got `pid is ok`
thank you for your help, I forgot to thank you at the beginning

Comment: @ s_ha_dum I can't solve the problem, I tried many ways but I can't, do you have any suggest?